# How to describe simultaneous events between two observers?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, observers

We have two observers, A who is stationary and B who is moving.
We have two points C and D that are equidistant from A.
At the exact moment B passes A (from A's perspective, if relevant) moving towards C (and at such a distance that in the moment that B passes A, BC = AC in terms of line length, again from A's perspective), light is emitted from C and D.
B will encounter the light from C first, then from D, while A will encounter both beams simultaneously (as I understand things).
My question comes about what A observes about B, especially if B 'reacts' to C (say by sneezing). The events I'm trying to get in order, from each perspective, are as follows:

1. B is beside A
2. C emits light
3. D emits light
4. A encounters C
5. A encounters D
6. B encounters C
7. B encounters D
8. B sneezes
9. A observes B encountering C
10. A observes B encountering D
11. A observes B sneezing
12. B observes A encountering C
13. B observes A encountering D

Attempting to see if I have this right, then:
From A's perspective it goes:

1. B is beside A
2. C emits light, D emits light
3. B encounters C
4. B sneezes
5. A encounters C, A encounters D
6. B encounters D
7. A observes B encountering C
8. A observes B sneezing
9. B observes A encountering C, B observes A encountering D
10. A observes B encountering D

From B's perspective:

1. B is beside A
2. C emits light
3. D emits light
4. B encounters D
5. B sneezes
6. A encounters C, A encounters D
7. B encounters C
8. A observes B encountering C
9. A observes B sneezing
10. A observes B encountering D
11. B observes A encountering C, B observes A encountering D

... Is that close to it?

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with simultaneity in special relativity, it is always a good idea to draw a [spacetime diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_diagram)<sup>1</sup>. In the diagram below, I have scaled the axes (hence the $ct$ instead of just $t$) such that light (represented by yellow lines) is at a 45°-angle (this is a convention that you will often see in spacetime diagrams) and I chose the moment where B passes A to be $t=t'=0$; $x=x'=0$. In this case, I chose the velocity of the train (and thus observer B) to be about $0.364c$ which corresponds to a 20°-angle with the $ct$-axis.

[image]

I also added the [worldlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line) for observers A and B

For a general process to find simultaneous events in different frames using a spacetime diagram, start by drawing the events in one observer's coordinate system (the "stationary" one). Then, you just have to think what the coordinate system will look like for a moving observer. Since [the coordinate axes for this observer are tilted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/587399/), simultaneity changes but you will be able to simply read it from the diagram.

We arrive at the following order for observer A (each line represents a simultaneity line, i.e. events that are simulatneous for A):

1. B passes A (AB), D emits light (D), C emits light (C)
2. B encounters the light ray from C (BC), B sneezes
3. A encounters the light rays from D (DA) and C (CA), A observes B sneezing
4. B encounters the light ray from D (DB)

For observer B the coordinate system is different (The dotted line shows the time coordinate of each event in B's frame $-$ if you wanted to find the $x$ coordinates, you would draw lines parallel to the $ct$-axis and see where they intersect with the $x$ axis):

[image]

So the simultaneity is as follows:

1. C emits a light ray (C)
2. B passes A (AB)
3. D emits alight ray (D)
4. B receives the light ray from C
5. A receives both light rays (DA/CA)
6. B receives the light ray from D

You will have noticed that I left out the events where B passes D and C, and A observes this. I will leave it to you to figure this out for each frame using your a method of your choice.

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't know how familiar you are with spacetime/Minkonwski diagrams. They are extremely useful in special relativity and thus worth learning. They can be intimidating at first (one seemingly confusing thing is that $x$ and $t$ axes are interchanged $-$ $x$ is horizontal and $ct$ is vertical instead of the other way around), but once you spend some time thinking about them, they will stop to look confusing and be a very valuable tool. I recommend you to learn them.

Here are some ressources on spacetime diagrams:

- [Spacetime diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_diagram) (Wikipedia)
- [Spacetime Diagrams | Special Relativity Ch. 2](https://youtu.be/hTxWAQGgeQw) (minutephysics on YouTube)
- [Introduction to special relativity and Minkowski spacetime diagrams](https://youtu.be/ii-KBKSODek) (Khan Academy on YouTube)
- [Special Relativity properties from Minkowski diagrams](https://arxiv.org/ftp/physics/papers/0703/0703002.pdf) by N. Penha and B. Rothenstein on arXiv<sup>2</sup>

<sup>2</sup> Be warned though that there are some errors later in the paper. See for example my question [How can it be that Doppler Factor k=1/k?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/587741/)

Comment: Lots confusion in SR comes from ppl thinking events (e.g., D,C) are stationary in one reference frame...which you imply by drawing world lines for them. Events are stationary in _all_ reference frames, so take out the vertical world lines and  the answer is a 100.

Comment: @JEB I meant to draw the world lines for the "locations" (flashlights or whatever they are) fpr C and D. Wouldn't this be correct? (Though I will edit my answer since this was apparently confusing)

Comment: Unfortunately, the original-poster used symbols that can lead to the confusion as @JEB describes. I prefer events labeled by a capital letter, like P, (like a point in a geometry book). Lines/rays/segments would be specified by an ordered pair of capital letters (like PQ)... and maybe even using names... like Alice is along PQ... or a lightray GH.  (An alternate notation is to label lines by lower-case letters and describe points as intersections of lines by specifying the pair of lines.... similar to what you have done, following the notation given by the original-poster.)

Comment: With the above notation... Using a pair of points, like PQ, to describe a segment also can be used to symbolize the proper time along that segment (technically one would say mPQ (measure of PQ).... but one could drop the m since i think it would be clear from the context).

Comment: An event exists at one $(t,x)$, which is $(t',x')$ in another frame..it's a point in  $M^4$. When you extend it to later $t$ you hold $x$ fixed, but then why can't you hold $x'$ fixed and extend it to later $t'$? Many ppl struggling with SR don't understand the difference, and how it implies a preferred frame when fixing someone's $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong in at least one point. A should encounter C (your 5.) simultaneous with A observing B encountering C (your 7.).

Consider if C emits two red photons simultaneously. Let B detect one of these photons (B encounters C), and instantaneously emit a single blue photon towards A. The remaining red photon and the new blue photon will move in step towards A. And A will detect the red photon (A encounters C) and the blue photon (A observes B encountering C) simultaneously.

There are other problems too: For example you state *"At the exact moment B passes A (from A's perspective, if relevant) moving towards C (and at such a distance that in the moment that B passes A, BC = AC in terms of line length, again from A's perspective), light is emitted from C and D."* so from A's perspective B passing and the emission of light from both C and D are simultaneous. But then you say that in A's point of view:
Attempting to see if I have this right, then: From A's perspective it goes:

1. B is beside A
2. C emits light, D emits light
3. ...

That is inconsistent